# LEX V2 Fulfillment lambda version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Does anybody have experience with the AWS LEX V2 **updateBotAlias** call in the AWS JavaScript SDK? How do you specify the lambda interface version (**codeHookInterfaceVersion**)? The lambda clearly has a version 1. It keeps saying:

`ValidationException: The specified Lambda function interface version isn't valid. Specify a different interface version and try your request again.`

By the way how do you specify the $LATEST?

This is my request:

```
{
  "botAliasId": "TSTALIASID",
  "botAliasName": "TestBotAlias",
  "botId": "3UR9######",
  "botAliasLocaleSettings": {
    "en_US": {
      "enabled": true,
      "codeHookSpecification": {
        "lambdaCodeHook": {
          "lambdaARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:##########93:function:fulfill-lambda",
          "codeHookInterfaceVersion": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "description": "en_US (Alias)"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me I'm sending:

```
codeHookSpecification: {
    lambdaCodeHook: {
        codeHookInterfaceVersion: '1.0',
        lambdaARN: botFunctionArn
    }
}
```

The ARN format ending in :function: is $LATEST.  If you want to connect your code hook to a specific version of the lambda function you would use an ARN ending in :function::

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it. It is the lex lambda event payload format version not the lambda version.